# mark specific content of a richTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, search, richtextbox, flowdocument

I would like specific content of a `richTextBox` after it was loaded mark colored (the `background 'of certain words change). When I click on a button to e.g. the word car to be marked. Now I found this code that I have to rebuild for my purposes.

```
public bool DoSearch(RichTextBox richTextBox, string searchText, bool searchNext)
       {
            TextRange searchRange;

            // Get the range to search
            if (searchNext)
                searchRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Selection.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(1),
                                            richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            else
                searchRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, 
                                            richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

            // Do the search
            TextRange foundRange = FindTextInRange(searchRange, searchText);
            if (foundRange == null)
                return false;

            // Select the found range
            richTextBox.Selection.Select(foundRange.Start, foundRange.End);
            return true;
        }

        public TextRange FindTextInRange(TextRange searchRange, string searchText)
        {
            // Search the text with IndexOf
            int offset = searchRange.Text.IndexOf(searchText);
            if (offset < 0)
                return null;  // Not found

            // Try to select the text as a contiguous range
            for (TextPointer start = searchRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(offset); 
                             start != searchRange.End; 
                             start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(1))
            {
                TextRange result = new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(searchText.Length));
                if (result.Text == searchText)
                    return result;

            }
            return null;
        }
```

can someone help me?

Comment: I want to change the background from a word in a `richtextbox`. With this Code i can search a word and now i have to insert it in a flowdocument, change the background and take it back to the richtextbox at the same position befor. But i dont know how i can do this.

Comment: Where is the FlowDocument coming from? You certainly don't need that.

Comment: I was think that i need a `FlowDocument`. On start of the program i load a .txt-file with the `FlowDocument` in the `Richtextbox`

Comment: This question helped me... The fool people doesn't know something about WPF. Some people like them are spoiling stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this link, contains a function HighlightPhrase which can change The Color of Specific Word in Rich textbox. Following this function try to investigate how to change background.

[How to Change The Color of Specific Word in Rich textbox using C#](http://r4r.co.in/c1/01/tutorial/csharp/How%20to%20Change%20The%20Color%20of%20Specific%20Word%20in%20Rich%20textbox%20using%20C-Sharp.shtml)

Comment: its work for windows forms, but SelectionStart, SelectionColor, SelectionLength are not available in WPF

Comment: how does it work in WPF ?